# MEF assembly loading declarations

Tags: prism, mef, assembly-resolution, assembly-loading

In Prism, I have the ability to declare from my dynamically loaded assembly how I expect the loading assembly to initialize me and when.  That is, I could place the following class attribute:

[ModuleExport(typeof(MyModule), InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable)]

Which would cause my module to be initialized as it's loaded.

I was looking for the ability to do the same with MEF, but I am not very familiar with it yet.  I tried searching around on MSDN and the documentation, but I didn't see much.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MEF doesn't have anything like this built in.  In Prism, the InitializationMode is metadata on the export, that the corresponding importer looks at and follows.  So you could use the same kind of convention in your application if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish but if you just want to do some work when MEF is finished initializing you then you can implement [IPartImportsSatsifiedNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.ipartimportssatisfiednotification.aspx) and get a callback when it finishes satisfying your imports.